# pocket-sized address book

Tags: tables, paper-size, crop

Do you know of any latex example or a package that I could use to print a pocket sized paper? All records will have a format like this:

> | name | phone | e-mail |

It would contain only 15 records for now so I think an A6 or A7 would be a good paper size.

UPDATE: It would be nice to have **cropping marks** to help me cutting the A6 or A7 paper shape. I would like to fill an A4 paper with those pocket-sized phone books and then cut them for my 15 friends in the list.

Comment: It seems as if the [`directory`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/directory/) package could do this for you (although I've never used it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cant u just make a file like this on a6 paper:

```
\begin{tabbing}
namename \= phonephone \= email \kill
John Doe \> 555-555 \> johndoe@hotmail.com \\
\end{tabbing}
```

Or with a simple table?

```
\begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm} }
John Doe & 555-555 & johndoe@hotmail.com \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

My testfile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wasysym} 
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
paperwidth=4.13in,
paperheight=5.83in,
margin=2em,
bottom=1.5em,
nohead
}
\usepackage[cam, a4]{crop}
\begin{document}
\crop[cross]
\begin{tabbing}
name name name \= phonephone \= email \kill
\male \ John Doe \> \phone \ 555-555 \> \Letter\ johndoe@hotmail.com \\
\end{tabbing}


\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{2cm}p{2cm} }
\male \ John Doe & \phone \ 555-555 &\Letter johndoe@hotmail.com \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: thx but, if it's possible, can you post the complete latex code?

Comment: Added =) This works for u?

Comment: Sure, It's a start. So you got my +1, but I'm searching for a little more :) like cropping marks and some symbol (a phone and a mail envelope for example)

Comment: U can do so using the http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/fonts/psfonts/marvosym/marvodoc.pdf package

Comment: @microspino: most often you can't expect a solution custom-tailored for your needs that is already made -- especially if you didn't specify what you really wanted in the first place. Telephone and mail symbols are really easy to add (http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf, or tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/fonts/psfonts/marvosym/marvodoc.pdf as Elmer suggested). What kind of cropping marks did you want? You might consider editing your question to include those additional requirements. As-is, you have been given a complete, simple and useful answer.

Comment: I have added an example with a phone and male/female logo. I guess this solves ur problem. Its easy to find on google btw.

Comment: @ipavlic I don't pretend a custom solution, symbols are a plus and I already upvoted @Elmer and @xport because they reduced already the work I need to do. I'm pretty satisfied but I'm just waiting for a while to see if some other solution arise. I added the reason I need A6/7 cropping marks. I thought It would be useful for other people/projects too.

Comment: @microspino i have added a6 size cropmarks on a4 paper, this what u looking for?

Comment: @Elmer brilliant. THX man. Accepted!

Answer (score 9):

[image]

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,10pt]{article}
\usepackage
[
a6paper,
margin=5mm
]
{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable,array}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\centering\sf
\rowcolors{2}{Green!10}{Yellow!10}
\begin{longtable}{*{4}{>{\scriptsize}c}}
\rowcolor{Gray!20}
\raisebox{-0.5pt}{\textbf{Gender}} & \raisebox{-0.5pt}{\textbf{Name}} & \raisebox{-0.8pt}{\Large\Telefon} & \raisebox{-2.5pt}{\Large\Email} \\
\Mars  & Barrack Obama        & 01234567 & barrack@obama.com \\ 
\Mars  & Steven Spielberg     & 01234567 & steven@spielberg.com \\ 
\Venus & Sarah Louise Palin   & 01234567 & sarah.louise@palin.com \\ 
\Mars  & Donald E. Knuth      & 01234567 & donald.e@knuth.com \\ 
\Mars  & Steve Jobs           & 01234567 & steve@jobs.com \\ 
\Venus & xport                & 01234567 & xport@tex.com \\ 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could also look at auto-generating the table using the `datatool` package, say from a `.csv` original. (That of course is most useful for bigger tables.)

Comment: Nice answer, not sure about the gender symbol if needed or not, seems a bit unecessary. I would also suggest a clickable mail address.

Comment: So that is how you can spend so much time here, xport! You are in fact six people at the same time! Nice answer, by the way.

Comment: As you're already using `marvosym` at any rate, I suggest using its `\Male` and `\Female` symbols instead of `\Mars` and `\Venus`. This would be semantically cleaner and I think the astronomical symbols, which you're using, would have an odd look for gender symbols, they look more like the letter "O" with something attached to it rather  than a circle with something.